# e.srcElement is undefined in firefox?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website and now am testing in all browsers, I am currently testing in firefox and have found and error when using event.sourceElement?

What i need e.srcElement to do is return values, a bit below i show an example on how i get the value PropID returned.

I have written a Jquery function that uses the e.srcElement and it looks as follows:

```
$(function () {
        $(".DownloadLink").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var PropID = getParameterByName("PropID", e.srcElement.search),
                Token = getParameterByName("Token", e.srcElement.search),
                TrackingNumber = getParameterByName("TrackingNumber", e.srcElement.search);

            $.post("Valuation", { PropID: PropID, Token: Token, TrackingNumber: TrackingNumber}, function (taskId) {

                // Init monitors

                $("#dialog-modal").append($("<p id='" + taskId + "'/>"));
                updateMonitor(taskId, "Started");

                // Periodically update Modal
                var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                    $.post("Progress", { id: taskId }, function (progress) {
                        if (progress < 50) {
                            updateMonitor(taskId, "Building File");
                        } else if (progress == 50) {
                            updateMonitor(taskId, "Uploading File to FormMobi");
                        } else if (progress >= 100) {
                            clearInterval(intervalId);
                            updateMonitor(taskId, "Complete");
                            window.location.href = "downloadcomplete";
                        }
                    });
                }, 100);
            });
        });
```

---

**example of how e.srcElement works:**

While testing in chrome and using the inspect element i can find that the following line returns:

Line of code:

> PropID = getParameterByName("PropID", e.srcElement.search)

Returned result:

> search:
>   "?PropID=77301&Token=74d30c0e-b4ab-4164-9dfd-f35fd7091cdc&TrackingNumber=367"

And so i can get the PropID result needed.

---

Is there some other why for me to return the values needed? Or
How can i get e.srcElement to work in fireFox?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in firefox simply call `e.target` to work. instead of `e.srcElement`[which works only in IE]

Comment: e.target will work in all browsers otherthan IE.In IE you need to call e.srcElement

Comment: Ok Thanks, and will i call e.target.search or just e.target?

Comment: e.target instead of e.srcElement

Comment: True, but Chrome seems to return also e.srcElement.

Comment: FYI `e.target` works in recent IE too. Didn't check how far back it started.

Answer (score 8):

```
function getTarget(obj) {
    var targ;
    var e=obj;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    return targ;
}
```

Will return the target for all browsers if you pass it e

from:- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Answer (score 2):

Simple as

```
var val= (e.srcElement||e.target).value;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: please explain your answer in few more words, otherwise it seems like comment.