# Ember-data how to bind a file upload to model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

There are bunch of answer on how to jQuery upload. That's not what I want. I want to simply bind the "file" input so that it's send with my object when I submit the form.

```
App.Document = DS.Model.extend({
    document_name: DS.attr(),
    document_file: DS.attr()
});

<form role="form" {{action save on="submit"}}>
    <div class="thumbnail" {{action 'start'}}>
        <img {{bindAttr src=src}} class="preview"/>
        <img class="shadow hide"/>
        <canvas class="hide"></canvas>
    </div>

   {{input type="file" valueBinding="document_file" name="document_file" }}

   {{input type="text" valueBinding="document_name" name="document_name"}}

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I haven't found a single tutorial on simple upload. It can't be too hard to send a file right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple to do it althougt it is not functionality out of the box. See my question here with working example: [Ember.js value binding with HTML5 file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909267/ember-js-value-binding-with-html5-file-upload)

Comment: It's kind of working. I see the data being bind as a huge string to my model. But when I submit my form, my backend see nothing in the $_FILES super variable. How am I suppose to move it if I can't see the temp name? Do I need to manually create the file?

Comment: @DelphilLynx Another thing that is very annoying is that it doesn't seem to be cross browser compatible. It works on Chrome, however if you open firebug in firefox, you will see that the "image" is null. Any idea on that?

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve You are programming in PHP? Yea it is tricky to get the files. You need to do it this way: `file_get_contents('php://input')`. To test it, send the data immediately back with: die(file_get_contents('php://input')). You should see in your data back.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve it is indeed not cross browser compatible. But I see the error immediately in Firefox: `TypeError: e.srcElement is undefined`. We need to dive deeper on this. Edit: Haha, one search on Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602039/e-srcelement-is-undefined-in-firefox Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve I updated the code of the fileupload, it is cross browser compatible now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909267/ember-js-value-binding-with-html5-file-upload/19910677#19910677

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data doesn't support it out of the box, you'll need to override the adapter and implement your own version of the createRecord/updateRecord which modifies the ajax call.  It's probably easier to just use jquery.

Comment: It's hard to believe that they didn't think someone would like to implement a simple file upload?!!! Are you 100% sure that this is a fact and there is no way to bind a file input to a model?!

Comment: Why is it hard to believe? There are libraries that are built just for uploading files, it isn't an simple task.  Uploading a file is quite different than inputting things like strings/numbers/booleans/dates (the included transforms). When you try and send the file it would need to be serialized, and are you going to send it as json or are you going to make a multipart call?  This is why it isn't built in as the default.