# Form data not appending values/image using Angular 4

Tags: php, angular

Hello friends I created a project in angular 4 I want to upload an image and sent request to the PHP file but form-data can't append values and images.
please help me 
I include FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, Http

```
const Image = this.com_Image.nativeElement;
if (Image.files && Image.files[0]) {
  this.comImageFile = Image.files[0];
}
const ImageFile: File = this.comImageFile;

// [enter image description here][1]
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('companyName', value.companyName);
formData.append('username', value.username);
formData.append('uploadFile', ImageFile, ImageFile.name);

console.log(formData);
```

Comment: Is sending it as a base64 string an option for you?

Comment: no i cant find result i my formdata

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pass only name and value for the image?

For file management (in general) this has worked for me:

```
formData.append('uploadFile', ImageFile);
```

Comment: formdata append is not working without image upload also

Answer (score 1):

**Html**

```
<input #fileSelect type="file" class="form-control" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" accept=".jpg, .png"/>
```

**component**

```
export class FileUploadComponent {
  @ViewChild('fileSelect') fileSelectInput: ElementRef;

  fileToUpload: any;

  onFileChanged(event) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602039/e-srcelement-is-undefined-in-firefox
    this.fileToUpload = (event.srcElement || event.target).files; 
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload[0]);
    this.createOrUpdateResource(formData);   
  }

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059121/angular4-file-upload-put-request-fails, 
  so making this POST
  private createOrUpdateResource(formData: FormData) {
    this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8080/upload`, formData).subscribe((res) => {
      //success
    }, error => {
      //error
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i have a doubt bro formdata append is not working without image upload also

Comment: @James what do you mean by formdata append not working?

Comment: can't append values in the formdata